# Adding SVN arguments in maven-release-plugin

Tags: java, svn, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

During a `mvn release:prepare`, maven-release-plugin needs to make some commits (tag and new poms).

I need to be able to add arguments to this SVN command without changing anything but the pom.xml file.

Comment: The maven-release-plugin already does this things. What kind of arguments do you need to add ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I know the plugin add some arguments, I want just to be able to add a few more

Comment: And which? I already asked that. And why?

Comment: @khmarbaise for now, --encoding --trust-server-cert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the developers of the maven-release-plugin themselves had to use a **separate file**

`svn-settings.xml`

to add an argument to the commits (as you can see in the link bellow), this question may not have a solution yet.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-628